# onItemClick option change the background color

Tags: android

How to implement when I click item option, the background color or images need to be change?

For example: listview have two options {item1, item2} .The default color is gray. After I click item1, the background color changes to blue. After click item2 the item1’s color change back grey, and item2’s background color change to blue.

Comment: paste code which you have try..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]selector+in+android

Comment: do you mean to say, that you want your each item clickable in listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for option menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu) {
    switch (menu.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menuitem1:

        //Do background or color task here

        break;

        case R.id.menuitem2:

       //Do background or color task here

        break;

        default:
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```